# Why is my process stuck in soldering (running state)?

Tags: c#, moryx

I have a MORYX application with several steps in a workplan. When I start an order that uses the workplan, the first steps run through without issues, but when I reach the soldering step the process is stuck without any notification or error on the UI or in the logs.

This is what the process looks like:
[image: Processes]

And this is the used workplan:
[image: Workplan]

So far I've tried different products and workplans (without the soldering step everything works fine) but I'm not sure how to solve this, because I don't see any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out myself:

The soldering isn't really stuck, the product is just waiting for manual soldering in the Worker Support tab...

If you haven't selected a client in the Worker Support, you don't get the notification that there are open tasks. After selecting a client, everything works as intended.

[User notification as normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7sXb.png)

[Select Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggrFl.png)

Same thing happens btw if you delete the cookies. So always check if you've selected a client / display after setup or deleting all cookies.